# This says I voted on the suggested edit even though I did not

Tags: bug, status-review, review-queues, suggested-edits

[This](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/164) is a suggested edit on one of my own posts. The notice above shows that I *voted on this suggested edit to [my] post as noted below.* However I did not such thing. Neither those reviewers are me. Can someone explain what is going here?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Did you click to approve the edit? It shows in [the post's activity timeline](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/posts/111/timeline) as "vote accept".

Comment: @kaya3 "Vote accept" is when you checkmark an answer.

Comment: @MichaelHomer Oh! That makes sense. Still, I can imagine if the OP clicked to "approve" a suggested edit, the system might count that as a vote without the OP thinking they had voted on anything.